# Prove that $K^{\times}=\langle \alpha \rangle$ where $\alpha$ is transcendental cannot be true.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, cyclic-groups

$K$ is an infinite field of characteristic $p\gt0$. Prove that the multiplicative group $K^{\times}=K\setminus\{0\}$ is not cyclic.

I want to consider this problem by two cases. One is to prove that it cannot be true when $K^{\times}=\langle \alpha \rangle$ where $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Z_p$ which is viewed as the prime field of $K$. With people's help, I have understood this case.

However, I have no idea how to prove that it is also not true that $K^{\times}=\langle \alpha \rangle$ when $\alpha$ is transcendental over $\mathbb Z_p$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $K^\times=\left<\alpha\right>$ then how can $\alpha+1$ be a power of $\alpha$?

Comment: Small notation advice: avoid using $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in the context of field theory, it is easy to confuse it with the $p$-adic integers. Use either $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (especially if you're seeing as a group) or $\mathbb{F}_p$ (especially if you're seeing it as a field).

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455902/show-that-the-multiplicative-group-k-times-k-setminus-0-is-not-cyclic).